# 2 Macros in 1 worksheet, single click for check mark and double click for x

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to combine 2 macros into 1 worksheet, I just want to utilize my mouse with a single click for a check mark and double click for x how can I do this? I attached the macro that I use it's the same formula: the string = "C2:C80, E2:E80" and Target.Value = "r" for the second macro. Target.Cells.Counts = 2

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const sCheckAddress As String = "B2:B80, D2:D80"

    Dim rngIntersect As Range

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngIntersect = Intersect(Me.Range(sCheckAddress), Target)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not (rngIntersect Is Nothing) Then
            Target.Font.Name = "Marlett"
        Target.Value = "a"


        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the language here - you have tagged it as sql and the code is not SQL

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You want this one macro to fire on two different events?  Do you have a check box object on your worksheet or are you just typing something into a cell on the worksheet?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do has to be split in to two separate events:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Const sCheckAddress As String = "B2:B80, D2:D80"

    Dim rngIntersect As Range

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngIntersect = Intersect(Me.Range(sCheckAddress), Target)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not (rngIntersect Is Nothing) Then
            Target.Font.Name = "Marlett"
        Target.Value = "r"
        ' I'm not overly happy with this next line, but at least it gets you out of activating the cell.
        Target.Offset(0, 1).Select
        End If

    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Const sCheckAddress As String = "B2:B80, D2:D80"

    Dim rngIntersect As Range

    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then

        On Error Resume Next
        Set rngIntersect = Intersect(Me.Range(sCheckAddress), Target)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not (rngIntersect Is Nothing) Then
            Target.Font.Name = "Marlett"
        Target.Value = "a"


        End If

    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

@sous2817 posted a good answer. I want to expand on that idea -- but if you like the approach please give @sous2817 credit for the answer since all I am doing is modifying that a little bit.

Whenever you are repeating code it is a good practice to think about how you can subroutine it or turn parts of it in to functions that you can use and re-use.

This compartmentalizes your code, makes it more legible (generally) and perhaps most importantly makes maintenance easier if the structure of your file later requires changes to the code.  For example, you have many common elements in both subroutines:

- `sCheckAddress` string variable representing a range address
- check whether target.cells.count = 1
- check whether target intersects `sCheckAddress

I put these common elements in a function that tells the subroutine when to act on the Target.  Although this may seem trivial on a project of this scope, it is a good habit to develop as you work on larger and more complicated VBA programming.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

Application.EnableEvents = False

If UpdateCell(Target) Then  `<~~ Use a custom function to determine whether to act on this cell.
    With Target
        .Font.Name = "Marlett"
        .Value = "r"
        .Offset(0, 1).Select
    End With
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False

If UpdateCell(Target) Then `<~~ Use a custom function to determine whether to act on this cell.
    With Target
        .Font.Name = "Marlett"
        .Value = "r"
    End With
End If

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Here is the function that checks to make sure your `Target`'s range is only ONE cell.  It also performs the second check to make sure that the `Target` instersects your `sCheckAddress`.  It returns a value of `True` *only if* it passes both of those conditions, which then allow the event macro to update the `Target`.

```
Private Function UpdateCell(rng As Range) As Boolean
Const sCheckAddress As String = "B2:B80, D2:D80"

'Establish conditions that return "FALSE"
If rng.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Function  '<~~ Make sure only one cell triggered the event.'
If Intersect(Me.Range(sCheckAddress), rng) Is Nothing Then Exit Function  '<~~ Make sure the cell is in your sCheckAddress Range.'

UpdateCell = True

End Function
```